# Only first page loads javascript in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I've read a lot of posts on this but none seem to help me.

Ive made the coding on the first page and second page the exact same and they are in the same directory but only the first page loads the javascript.

Here is the code of the second page. (same as the first page but the first has a link to this page and no back link in the header)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">




    <title>San Angelico Museum of Contemporary Art</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css">


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>


    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/widgets/widget-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="js/widgets/widget-filter.js"></script>

        <script id="js">$(function() {

    var $table = $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
        widgetOptions : {
            // filter_anyMatch replaced! Instead use the filter_external option
            // Set to use a jQuery selector (or jQuery object) pointing to the
            // external filter (column specific or any match)
            filter_external : '.search',
            // add a default type search to the first name column
            filter_defaultFilter: { 1 : '~{query}' },
            // include column filters
            filter_columnFilters: false,
            filter_placeholder: { search : 'Search...' },
            filter_saveFilters : true,
            filter_reset: '.reset'
        }
    });
    // make demo search buttons work
    $('button[data-column]').on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            totalColumns = $table[0].config.columns,
            col = $this.data('column'), // zero-based index or "all"
            filter = [];

        // text to add to filter
        filter[ col === 'all' ? totalColumns : col ] = $this.text();
        $table.trigger('search', [ filter ]);
        return false;
    });

});</script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
    </script>

</head>


<body>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">

    <p><a href="index.html">back</a></p>

    </div>




    <div id="main" data-role="main" class="ui-content">

     <p>hello world</p>

        <div id="demo"><input class="search" type="search" data-column="all"> 






<table  data-role="table" id="tablepress" data-mode="columntoggle" class="tablesorter ui-responsive">
<thead>
<tr class="row-1 odd">
    <th class="column-1">#</th><th data-priority="1" class="column-2">Title</th><th class="column-3">Percent Filler</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="row-hover">
<tr class="row-2 even">
    <td class="column-1">1</td><td class="column-2"><a href="/shows/naruto-shippuden/homecoming-2" rel="nofollow">Homecoming</a></td><td class="column-3"><div id="progress" class="graph"><div id="bar" style="width:100%"><p>100% Filler</p></div></div></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>


    </div>



    <div data-role="footer">
        <div id="red"> <p>footer</p> </div>
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the second page that the coding JS isn't working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user3234020,
you have two (2) problems with your code. They are both related.

1. When you create `$table = $('table').tablesorter({`, the table still have not loaded. So there is a good chance that is not being seen by Javascript. So, it silently fails, rather than execute. TO FIX THIS, *move the code to the bottom of the page.*
2. You are not properly waiting for the `'deviceready'` event. For Cordova/Phonegap you **MUST** wait the 'deviceready' event before you do anything at all; including calling support libraries

The information you need comes from #4 of  [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md). I quote:

> **4. In the code, did not listen for the 'deviceready' event.**
>
> This is listed MULTIPLE times in the documentation, and is include in every example where it is appropriate. It is still missed. [Brian Ford](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-phonegap) - an Angular developer, points to the [section of documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) we need.
>
> *This is a very important event that every Cordova application should use.*
>
> *Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However, JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function before it is loaded.*
>
> *The Cordova deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova function.*
>
> And in case you think this is minor, even veterans like Raymond Camden [have forgotten this](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/07/15/fyi-cordova-events-must-be-run-after-deviceready).

Comment: Wow that answer was great thanks it helped heaps it works now that i have the JS code at the bottom. But I still don't understand where and when the 'deviceready' event is called. do i need to call things under a certain include file? or if I call things at the bottom of the file i guarantee deviceready going to be called by the time that code is reached.

Comment: @user3234020, You can setup the `deviceready` event anywhere you want. It can go before the first Javascript file you load, if you want. However, ANY Javascript you call MUST be after the `deviceready` event has fired. This includes any JQuery, Angular, or Bootstrap. &ndash; Basically, Cordova/Phonegap are not ready until this event has fired. This means many service *will not* work until this event fires. This includes, but is not limited to, motion sensors, GPS, bluetooth and networking. To be clear, these services may work, but Cordova does not guarantee those services until the event fires